# What parameter name to use for ArgumentException in property setters

Tags: vb.net, exception

From MSDN:

> Every ArgumentException should carry the name of the parameter that causes this exception.

My question: if a property setter should throw an `ArgumentException`, should I give it the setter's parameter name (default: `value`) or the name of the property?

Example:

```
    Private _myProperty As String
    Public Property MyProperty As String
        Get
            Return _myProperty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
                ' what I've been doing for the last 2 years
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("value", "value cannot be empty")

                ' what I think I should be doing instead
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("MyProperty", "value cannot be empty")
            End If
            _myProperty = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I hope that made sense. What do you think?

**Edit**

I guess another solution would be to rename `value` to something more meaningful, then use that as the value for `paramName`. But somehow that doesn't seem like it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to an example from [Catching and Throwing Standard Exception Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx) on MSDN you should keep setting "value" as a parameter name:

> Do use value for the name of the implicit value parameter of property
>   setters.

So that's ok:

```
Throw New ArgumentNullException("value", "value cannot be empty")
```

Comment: Nice! Somehow that page didn't come up in my Google search results. Thanks.